# Opening *.pmf file using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, qgis-plugins, qgis-2, pmf

I have spatial data that has been put together with ArcGIS for Desktop and exported to me as a .pmf file.

How can I use the .pmf file in QGIS?

There are about 1000 points and I don't want to have to redo this work.

Do I have to convert it to something else so I can import it to QGIS? If so, can someone suggest a converter program?

I also have the points in an Excel file.

Answer (score 2):

The .pmf file is a document file that references GIS data from another source, so it cannot be exported and only viewed using ArcReader:

> ArcReader can only read data through a PMF. The PMF supports access to
>   all standard vector and raster formats supported by ArcGIS. The PMF
>   does not include the data. Rather, the PMF references the data whether
>   it is on a local drive, a shared network drive, or an Internet
>   service. The PMF preserves a live connection to the data, so the
>   user's data view is dynamic.

If the excel file has x/y or lat/lng coordinates, then you can simply convert it to a .csv and load it into QGIS using the **Add Delimited Text Layer** button.  Once you see the points in the map you can export (Save As) this point event layer to whatever GIS format you would like (e.g. shapefile, file geodatabase...etc).

Comment: Thank you! The Excel file has Radius Easting and Radius Northing coordinates. Will that suffice for x/y coordinates? Is there a particular way I need the x/y columns to be organized/labeled in order for it to be imported correctly?